# ruby whenever gem log location in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, whenever

I'm running the whenever (cron) gem on Ubuntu 11 and can't seem to find where the log is or where to set the log file. I think something is amiss and I can't seem to be able to debug it without the log file.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you've missed it. Whenever's github wiki has a page for this: [Output redirection aka logging your cron jobs](https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/Output-redirection-aka-logging-your-cron-jobs)

Answer (score 0):

The cron log will tell you when cron jobs are run and changed. By default, Ubuntu disables the cron log.

The following steps will enable the cron log to allow for better debugging details.

```
Edit /etc/syslog.conf and uncomment the line starting with cron.*
Run /etc/init.d/sysklogd restart
Run /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

The results of a commands run by cron have to be logged by you: [see James's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086925/ruby-whenever-gem-log-location-in-ubuntu/7086971#7086971)